# How to compare two different times (minutes) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My if statement currMin < minutesToExpire will never go through the 'else' portion of the logic, even when currMin is greater than minutesToExpire. For example, if the current time is 11:02 , the minutesToExpire will be 11:04, and if I were to click the "Stay Logged In button" at 11:08, there should be a message that shows "Error" but it never shows! Am I comparing the times correctly?

```
   $("#button").click(function () {

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var currMin = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var minutesToExpire = currentTime.getMinutes() + 2;

  return $.ajax({
     url: 'Home/ResetSession',
     type: 'POST',
     data : {
    }
   })
     .done(function (data) {
       if ( currMin <= minutes ) {
          setTimeout();
          $("#timeoutModal").modal("hide");
     } else {
             $("#timeoutModal").modal("hide");
             showMessage("error);
     }


<div class="modal fade" id="timeoutModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="Session Timeout">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">`
<button id="button" type="button"> Stay Logged In </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you would like to compare ```currMin <= minutesToExpire```. The ```setTimeout()-Funktion``` has no meaning used in this way, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout. Be aware, that the comparison of minutes derived from date has only meaning if you stay in the same hour! You should compare timestamps instead: ```Date.getTime()```-

Comment: Ideally you should not be comparing the minutes like this. Get current time as epoch and add 2*60*1000  to it to get a timestamp 2 minutes after your current.

Comment: How would I get current time as an epoch? something like var x = currentTime.getTime() + 2*60*1000; ??